# my merge sort is not giving proper sorted array, can anyone explain?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, merge

I am struggling for several hours to understand and implement this algorithm, I am pretty sure , I am doing everything according to standard algorithm , but still its not working.
I am following a book named "Introduction to algorithm by Thomas H cormen"

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

//function to divide the array until it has only one element
void merge_sort(int[], int, int);

// function to merge two sorted arrays
void merge(int[], int, int, int);

// global array - to write the final sorted array in this
int na[100];

void main() {
    int a[50]; //input array
    cout << "Enter an unsorted array of 10 elements" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        cin >> a[i];
    }
    merge_sort(a, 0, 9);  // calling merge_sort
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        //print final array
        cout << na[i] << endl;
    }
}

void merge_sort(int a[], int p, int r) {
    // p is 0 , r is final bound
    if (p < r) {
        int q;
        q = (p + r) / 2; //finding middle element
        merge_sort(a, p, q);
        merge_sort(a, q + 1, r);
        merge(a, p, q, r);
     }

}

// for two sorted sub-array from p to q and from q+1 to r, this function 
// will compare first element of each sub-array and will place the smaller 
// one in final array until every element is sub-array is in final sorted 
//array
void merge(int a[], int p, int q, int r) {
    int n1 = q - p + 1;
    int n2 = r - q;
    int l[50];
    int ri[50];
    for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++) {
        l[i] = a[p + i ];
    }
    l[n1] = 99999;

    for (int j = 0; j < n1; j++) {
        ri[j] = a[q + j + 1];
    }
    ri[n2] = 99999;

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    for (int k = p; k <= r; k++) {
         if (l[i] <= ri[j]) {
            na[k] = l[i];
            i = i + 1;
        }
        else {
            na[k] = ri[j];
            j = j + 1;
        }
     }

}
```

Comment: You should update your resources, `void main()` is inacceptable.

Comment: You can inspect the code and variables behavior stepping through line by line with your debugger.

Comment: 1) `j < n1;` --> `j < n2;`

Comment: 2) Don't use `int na[100];`. So `cout << na[i]` --> `cout << a[i]`, `na[k] = l[i];` --> `a[k] = l[i];` Because you are using `int a[]` as a sorted array.

Comment: oh..the 2 point worked @bluepixy , but how writing result to a worked and na not? if u dont mind

Comment: You must use sorted sequence as the integration. You are using `a` that is not sorted instead.

Comment: got it , that was helpful @BLUEPIXY

Answer (score 0):

You are using values in `a` to merge, but you are putting sorted subarrays in `na`. The `merge` operation will only give you a sorted array if the subarrays are sorted. As BLUEPIXY suggests, you need to be using one container for storing sorted subarrays and for merging sorted subarrays: whether you use `a` or `na` for that purpose is immaterial but `a` would be the better choice since you already have it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to read the guidelines for asking a question on StackOverflow.
2. In mergeSort , you are merging unsorted arrays instead of the sorted ones (`void merge_sort(int a[], int p, int r)` : since you are merging `a[]`, you should sort `a[]` and not `na[]`).

Otherwise merge segments of `na[]` and copy it to `a[]` in each function call to merge_sort(:);